# PHP - Uploaded file not sending to file directory

Tags: php, file, pdo

On my website, I allow users to submit files and they are sent to the database and a file directory, devFiles, I created. It sends to the database fine, but when i send it to the directory, it never sends and i get my error message i created to see if it sends or not. I believe the problem is with the

```
if(is_file($dir.'/'.$file_name)==false){
        //code...

       }
```

but i tried change the condition but it didn't work. So what i want to do is, send the file that was submitted to the file directory on hand that was created. Here is my code

PHP

```
$query = "INSERT INTO pack_screenshots(pack_id, file_name, file_tmp)VALUES(:packid, :file_name, :file_tmp)";
$stmtFileUpload = $handler->prepare($query);
$errors = array();

foreach($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] as $key => $error){

if ($error != UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    $errors[] = $_FILES['file']['name'][$key] . ' was not uploaded.';
    continue;
    }

$file_tmp = file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key]);
$file_name = addslashes(trim($_FILES['file']['name'][$key]));
    try{

$stmtFileUpload->bindParam(':packid', $packid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmtFileUpload->bindParam(':file_name', $file_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmtFileUpload->bindParam(':file_tmp', $file_tmp, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$dir = "devFiles";

if(is_dir($dir)==false){

    mkdir($dir, 0700);
 }

if(is_file($dir.'/'.$file_name)==false){


    if(!move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$dir.'/'.$file_name)){

               die("File didn't send!");
          }

        }else{

         $_SESSION['invalid'] = true;
        header("Location: developer_invalid.php");
        exit;
        }
        $stmtFileUpload->execute();
        $_SESSION['thankyou'] = true;
        header("Location: developerUpload_thankyou.php");
        exit;
         }catch(PDOException $e){

            $errors[] = $file_name . 'not saved in db.';
            echo $e->getMessage();
                    }
                 }
```

Comment: Check your Apache error log to get a more detailed error message

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: on linux: `sudo vim /var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: Quick notice, your using addslashes() on the file name. And you use that in your directory path move_uploaded_file() ... if the user has an ' in it, it will add \' I wonder if PHP might interpret \ as a / and try to add the file to a sub directory that does not exist ... Never tested it but maby that could be it?

Comment: Also, is the tmp file really created? you can use print_r($_FILES) to see if there was an error creating it.

Comment: One last thing. Turn on error reporting if you can't access the log file error_reporting(-1);

Comment: this is what the error log told me "move_uploaded_file() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in"

Comment: Seems like it submitted fine because i didn't get any errors @PatrickSimard

Comment: Based on the error you gave, the problem is here $file_name = addslashes(trim($_FILES['file']['name'][$key])); Looks like it returns an array instead of a string

Comment: Can you dump $file_name please?

Comment: Oh sorry ... param 1 lol so $file_tmp is the culprit lol

Comment: So var dump $file_tmp? and if so i got this message ":\wamp64\www\MT\developerUpload.php:146:string"

Comment: Just to be safe here you did add enctype="multipart/form-data" to your form tag right?

Comment: Most definitely

Comment: Ok can you run this please and post the array in your question? echo "<pre>"; print_r($_FILES); echo "</pre>"; Lets check what you array looks like

Comment: "Array ( [file] => Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => receipt.jpg ) [type] => Array ( [0] => image/jpeg ) [tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => C:\wamp64\tmp\php2BFD.tmp ) [error] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) [size] => Array ( [0] => 1746682 ) ) ) "

Comment: Ok let's try something. for testing purpose lets manually give $key the value 0 after the start of the foreach loop. tell me if the file uploaded.

Comment: I didn't send to the directory

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150123/discussion-between-jagr-and-patrick-simard).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> PHP Documentation bool move_uploaded_file ( string $filename , string $destination )

You did :

```
move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$dir.'/'.$file_name)
```

move_uploaded_file is expecting $file_tmp to be a path to the tmp file but you used

```
$file_tmp = file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key]);
```

so $file_tmp is no longer the path but the content it self
So to solve the upload problem just use the tmp file path instead.

```
if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key],$dir.'/'.$file_name)){
```

Also, you should remove addslashes() on the file name because it could create unexpected results. Instead, you can sanitize the filename using something like this:

```
$file_name = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9\.]/", "_", strtolower($_FILES['file']['name'][$key]));
```

You should also consider adding a random number to the file name so users don't overwrite other users files that have the same name: me.png could be common for an avatar for example. Would be safer to save as

```
$filename = strtotime("now")."_me.png";
```

One last thing, using is_file() can also cause problems in certain cases

> Note: Because PHP's integer type is signed and many platforms use 32bit integers, some filesystem functions may return unexpected results for files which are larger than 2GB.

use file_exists() instead

Comment: Wow! Thanks for your help :D You didn't stop helping knowing I was confused :D I appreciate all your hard work to helping me find the correct way to do this and your tips and tricks